# Can Cascading rewritten/replaced Apache Spark & Scala? Is it more optimal?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, mapreduce, cascading

I have to replace map reduce code written in pig and java to Apache Spark & Scala as much as possible, and reuse or find an alternative where it is not possible.
I can find most of pig conversions to spark. Now, I have encountered with java cascading code of which I have minimal knowledge.
I have researched cascading and understood how plumbing works but i cannot come to a conclusion whether to replace it with spark. Here are my few basic doubts.

1. Can cascading java code completely be rewritten in Apache Spark?
2. If possible, Should Cascading code be replaced with Apache Spark? Is it more optimal and fast?(Considering RAM is not the issue for RDD's)
3. Scalding is a Scala library built on top of Cascading. Should this be used to convert java code to Scala code which will remove java source code dependency? Will this be more optimal?
4. Cascading works on mapreduce which reads I/O Stream whereas Spark reads from memory. Is this the only difference, or are there any limitations or special features which can be only performed by either one?

*I am very new to Big-Data segment, and very immature with concepts/comparisons of all Big-Data related terminologies Hadoop, Spark, Map-Reduce, Hive, Flink etc. I got hold of these Big Data responsibility with with my new job profile and minimal senior knowledge/experience. Please, provide answer explanatory if possible. Thanks*

Comment: Yes, Spark should be a lot faster than Cascading backed by Hadoop. Generally speaking, most use-cases solved with Cascading should also be solvable with Spark, but the possibility strictly depends on your use-case. Another suggestion - don't  suggest changes to you job ecosytem without actually having an in-depth understanding.

Comment: Converting Java to Scala, in most cases, is not more optimal for runtime, considering Scala is calling underlying Java methods. If you're working mostly with streams, then Flink or Beam might be better

Comment: Any learnings that you can share if you moved code from scalding/cascading to spark?